# Linq to Entities query result to a decimal variable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hello here's a query that get records from an Oracle database via linq to entities :

```
private void BareCode_TxtBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
        if (e.Key==Key.Enter)
        {
            string lot = string.Empty;
            string pnet = string.Empty;
            string nbuOracle = string.Empty;
            decimal pnetOracle = 0;

            #region récupérer le nb unités de la pesée dans GCPESEE Oracle
            using(Entities or=new Entities())
            {
                var query = from p in or.GCPESEE
                            where p.PESEE_LOT == lot
                            && p.PESEE_PDSNET == Convert.ToDecimal(pnet)
                            group new { p } by new
                            {
                                p.PESEE_NUM,
                                p.PESEE_LOT
                            } into grouped
                            select new
                            {
                                numpesee=grouped.Key.PESEE_NUM,
                                numlot=grouped.Key.PESEE_LOT,
                                pdsnet=grouped.Sum(x=>x.p.PESEE_PDSNET),
                                nbu=grouped.Sum(x=>x.p.PESEE_NBEMB)
                            };
                pnetOracle = (decimal)query.SingleOrDefault().pdsnet;
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }
```

then i want to use the result of this query in variables like this (it works with linq to sql…) :
" pnetOracle = (decimal)query.SingleOrDefault().pdsnet;"
But there i'm getting an error (sorry it's in French) :

[image]

I try to translate in English :
"Linq to Entities doesn't recognize string string To String method and can't translate it into a shop expression…"
something like that.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Best way is to add `Null` Checking after `SingleOrDefault()` on object. And then try to cast it into `decimal`.

Comment: You need to assign a value to _string pnet = string.Empty;_ before you use it the query. Also, if the _pnet_ type in the database is decimal, then declare the variable as decimal not as string so you don't need to do the conversion in the query. Also, check if the query yields return something before accessing the fields. use _pnetOracle = (decimal)query.SingleOrDefault()?.pdsnet;_ as Sushant Yelpale suggested. Good luck

Comment: Ok i try this and tell you if it works

Comment: That s it! Thank you very much

Comment: Most welcome. Good luck.